# A probability question for matching socks in N bins

Tags: probability

I thought of this problem while working on a separate problem trying to link records from two datasets. Suppose there are N bins, X red socks, and Y blue socks. Suppose we uniformly randomly throw the red socks and blue socks into the N bins. Two socks are considered a pair if they are in the same bin, one of them is red and one of them is blue. For example if there are 5 red socks and 8 blue socks in a bin, then that bin has 5 pairs of socks. What's the mean and variance of the number of pairs of socks we will find?

I ran a few simulations with N = 10 and 50, a fixed number of 100 blue socks, and varying the number of red socks from 10 to 200.

[Graph with simulations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9wJL.png)

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: If a bin has $k$ red socks and $k$ blue socks, does that count as $k$ pairs or $k^2$? Your wording seems to allow a particular sock to be a member of more than one "pair."

Comment: Hi, that would count as k pairs. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If $Z_i$ is the number of pairs in the $i$th bin then your random variable of interest is $\sum_{i=1}^N Z_i$.

Then $$E\left[\sum_{i=1}^N Z_i\right] = \sum_{i=1}^N E [Z_i] = N E[Z_1]$$ since the $Z_i$ have the same distribution (one bin is not different from the other when throwing the socks).

The event $\{Z_1 \ge j\}$ is equivalent to "there are at least $j$ red socks and at least $j$ blue socks in the first bin." Thus, by the tail sum formula for expectation,
$$E[Z_1] = \sum_{j=1}^{\min(X,Y)} P(Z_1 \ge j) = \sum_{j=1}^{\min(X,Y)} \sum_{m=j}^X \binom{X}{m} \frac{(N-1)^{X-m}}{N^X} \sum_{l = j}^Y \binom{Y}{m} \frac{(N-1)^{Y-l}}{N^Y}.$$
I could not think of a way to simplify this, nor of a different route that would be simpler. Perhaps someone more savvy could help you further.